# OperationalError at /admin/products/product/ about slugfield

Tags: python, django, django-models

my models.py

```
    from django.db import models

class Product(models.Model):
    category_name = models.CharField(max_length=60, default='')
    category_url = models.SlugField(max_length=200, unique=True, default='')

    def __str__(self):
        return "%s" % (self.category_name)

class Mobile_Brand(models.Model):
    brand = models.CharField(max_length=60, default='')
    brand_url = models.SlugField(max_length=200, unique=True, default='')

    def __str__(self):
        return "%s" % (self.brand)


class Mobile(models.Model):
    mobile_model = models.CharField(max_length=255, default='')
    mobile_brand = models.ForeignKey(Mobile_Brand,
        verbose_name="Mobile_Brand",
        on_delete=models.CASCADE 
    )
    category = models.ForeignKey(Product,
        verbose_name="Product",
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        default=''
    )
    mobile_img = models.ImageField(upload_to="mobile",default='')
    mobile_url = models.SlugField(max_length=200, unique=True, default='')
```

and after `makemigrations` and `migrate` when i go to admin page and Mobiles page or other ones, i see such errors

for Products section : `no such column: products_product.category_url`

for Mobiles section : `no such column: products_mobile.mobile_url`

for Moblie_Brands section : `no such column: products_mobile_brand.brand_url`

thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

Try that :

`python manage.py makemigrations products`

`python manage.py migrate products`